# Unable to find branch in git repo

Tags: git-branch, git-commit

In the current directory. I had made a repository yesterday from this directory.
now:
        git branch foo
After doing some changes in the file..
    git add .
    git commit -m "commit1"
    git push.
I am unable to see the branch from my repo on github. While git branch does show this foo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you did is creating a local branch;
you will need alternatively to make it a remote branch:

```
git push <remote-name> <branch-name>
```

where `<remote-name>` is usually `origin`

Comment: Also not that, `git branch foo` only creates a branch foo, it does no switch to foo! (Use `git checkout -b foo` to do both in one step)